# Kubernetes - Get the public URL of a service into my ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have my Kubernetes service of which I'm getting the url in my minikube installation using:

`minikube service postgres --url`

Which returns the URL like: `http://192.xxx.xx.xxxx:3xx62`

However I want this URL to be used in my ConfigMap as the pghost and pgport - so for example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: firsttest
  labels:
    app: firsttest
data:
  pgdatabase: "first_test"
  pguser: "postgresql_user"
  pghost: ""
  pgport: ""
  pgpool_size: "5"
  auth_user: "unique"
```

And the service looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: pgql
    port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: postgres
```

Is this possible?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, If you can write the service name and Port number of Postgresql in the configmap.  There is a dns record of each service `my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`  So other pod can find it.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi - Thanks - so what your saying is in the ConfigMap (as above) - I've added the Postgres service above in my question

Comment: Hi, you need to put these data in configmap `pghost: "postgres"`  and `pgport: "5432"`

Comment: But those values dont equal the URL I get when I do: `minikube service postgres --url` which looks like `http://192.xxx.xx.xxxx:3xx62`

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood then, I thought the purpose of it was service discovery.   I am wondering, Why you need to hardcode these values? by the way, for database its better to use `type=ClusterIP` instead of NodePort .

Comment: I dont need to hardcode it - I just can't find a way to get the URL - why is ClusterIP better?

Comment: `CluserIP` expose the database internally in the cluster which is secure relatively exposing it to the external world.

Comment: In single node It is possible to put IP address, but when you have more nodes it will be difficult since a pod can terminate anytime and come back on other nodes. Thus, Service discovery is optimal solutions to over come this challenge

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171215/discussion-between-usermod2-and-suresh-vishnoi).

Comment: Great it works, Port number needs to be same in Postgres service and in ConfigMap

Answer (score 0):

I will just compile a list of some crucial things about interaction with Services:

1. You can create a Service object before creating pods with services, it is OK.
2. To access the service inside a cluster, you should use "ClusterIP."
3. You cannot use variables like a name of a service, but you can use FQDN of the service, and it's IP address, which is **static** and will be available until you delete a service.
4. Service's IP and port are what you need to access pods behind a service.